# How can you restrict a user to making only SELECT statements on Google cloudSQL

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-sql, database-security

I am currently writing an application that uses google cloud SQL to query and display certain data.

Is there a way that I can programatically enforce that all queries made by the user will be SELECT statements? Or at least ruling out DML statements. For obvious reasons analysing the Query string is quite impractical.

If not, is there a way I can configure the SQL statements accepted by cloud SQL on the app engine configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new 'read only' user with only SELECT privileges and then use that user from your AppEngine app.

Instructions for setting up user permissions in MySQL:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html